# How to set userid for products added to cart in magento?

Tags: magento, cart

I am adding configurable products in to cart using the below code.

```
                $product_id = 123; 
                $qty        = 1; 
                $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
                $cart       = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); 
                $cart->init();

                $superAttributeArray = array('151' => '3');

                $params = array(
                            'product' => $product_id,
                            'qty'     => $qty,
                            'super_attribute' => $superAttributeArray
                             );
                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $cart->save();
```

this code works well and I can able to add the product in to cart. Tested the same in Database.

I want to map user id for the quote that was created.
products will be added only after loggging in.
When I add products with above code, customer_id field in 'sales_flat_quote' table is NULL. I want current logged in user id need to be set to this quote.

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```html
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     $customerId = $customerData->getId();
}
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: I can able to get the logged in customer id. But I want to map that user to the product added to cart ..!!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at adding this to the current customer user session (it doesn't matter if they're logged in or not then)

```
...
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);

$session = Mage::getSingleton(
    'core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')
);

$session->setLastAddedProductId($product->getId());
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```